# PHP Faster Prime Number generator

Tags: php, algorithm, bash, primes

hey guys I'm trying to squeeze more primes out of my generator but have hit a limit of +- 14,000,000 or so primes in a sixty second run, i'm looking to push that possibly up to 25-30 mil if possible. Any ideas on how to accomplish this feat?

Here's my php code

```
<?php
$i = 2;
$primes = array();
while(true)
{
    $prime=true;
    $sqrt=floor(sqrt($i));
    foreach($primes as $num)
    {
        if($i%$num==0)
        {
            $prime=false;
            break;
        }
        if($num>$sqrt) break;
    }
    if($prime) echo "$i\n";
    $i++;
}
```

And here's the little bash script to run it

```
#!/bin/bash
outfile="$1.out"
`php $1 > $outfile &`
sleep 60
killall php
```

**EDIT**

Here's a pcntl_forked version from last night just to see what would be faster.
For some weird reason, the less forking I did the faster if was, I found out the
bottlenecking was coming from `gmp_strval(gmp_nextprime($start))` which is extremely slow.

```
<?php
$primeCount = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1; ++$i) {
    $start = $i;
    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if (!$pid) {
        while(true) echo $start = gmp_strval(gmp_nextprime($start)) . "\n";
        exit($i);
    }
}

while (pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1) {
    $status = pcntl_wexitstatus($status);
    #echo "Child $status , $primeCount completed\n";
}
die;
```

Comment: Where are you putting your new prime into `$primes`?

Comment: This is a PHP project, I'm not switching languages =(

Comment: Running your code tells me that 4 is a prime.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn lol .... are you really suggesting op to use c ..? rofl

Comment: Well that has to be the bottleneck -- PHP.

Comment: @NullPointer if speed is what OP wants, then yes.

Comment: @NullPointer Yes, but it's not C. C is compiled for one thing.

Comment: does performance really matter... prime numbers are deterministic and should be cached instead of calculated if performance is an issue.

Comment: Yes, what is this for? Do the primes have to be in order?

Comment: I see where I'm not storing my primes, it should be `echo $primes[]="$i\n";` thats a huge fallacy =( I tried this with `gmp_nextprime` and also `gmp_prob_prime` but they are both extremely slow =(

Comment: @ehime - sorry about that; when I tested your code, it went from about 6 million numbers, to 700,000 primes.

Comment: No the primes don't have to be in order, as a matter of fact I wrote a pcntl_forked version yesterday that took slices at random, I'll post it up so you can compare, it is very slow though, about 63k primes. This was just a way to understand sieving. =)

Comment: @NullPointer yes, the php binaries are written in C, however php scripts having to be parsed and interpreted by php will never be anywhere near as fast as compiled C by itself. I would guess you would get something like a 20x or more increase by using C.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn agree with you ...

Comment: @JonathanKuhn agreed +1. I wish I could use C or Java, I'm pretty sure either would be faster than php

Comment: You know you can just download a list of primes, right? Why do you need to generate them?

Comment: @Sammitch why not generate them? its a fun personal code challenge to see what is faster why and how? You don't get good at programming by copying everyone elses work.

Comment: So you just arbitrarily set a goal of getting 30 million primes in a minute with PHP?

Comment: Yeah I think its possible? We had a PHP meeting last night, and the most anyone got while there was 7-10k, I thought I could do better, and I did with the pcntl_fork version by a large amount, I think I can do better than that even because I realize that gmp is my bottle neck and my forking is detrimental to the program, I thought this up whil (not working) at work =) I think I've hit the limits of my knowledge though of the algorithm to compute these though, so i'm reach out to you guys!

Comment: Take a good look at this: http://icdif.com/computing/2011/09/15/check-number-prime-number/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've been looking at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Efficient_Prime_Number_Generating_Algorithms#PGsimple4 right now and trying to figure out how to use a skip number in the above code, I think it could get it up by about 1.25x ??

Comment: I'm surprised nobody said it yet. This is one of the few questions where the "use a Sieve of Eratosthenes" advice is really appropriate.

Comment: @DanielFischer - is there a way to use the Sieve without knowing in advance what the upper limit is? I can use it to generate primes up to a given value, but for something like this, where you just want as many numbers as possible, I can't just put everything in one huge array.

Comment: @andrewsi One way to use a sieve here is to estimate how far you can go in the allotted time, and then take that as the limit. If you have a little time left, start trial division from the limit onwards. More generally applicable is making a segmented sieve. That's a bit more complicated than a monolithic sieve, but unless you go for the utmost efficiency still easy enough. Methinks PHP doesn't have real arrays, so it won't be too efficient, but it should still go orders of magnitude farther than trial division.

Comment: @DanielFischer - thanks, that's very helpful. I'm relieved to know that I was on the right track!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the exception of 2 and 3, all prime numbers are one above or one below a multiple of 6.  That should reduce your search space to roughly 1/3 instead of incrementing i by 1 each time.  Seed your sieve with 2,3 and use the reduced search space to speed up your time.

If you need a simple explanation of how this works:

```
1 + n*6 (This is one above, and I state it's got primes)
2 + n*6 (multiple of 2)
3 + n*6 (multiple of 3)
4 + n*6 (multiple of 2)
5 + n*6 (This is one below, and I state it's got primes)
6 + n*6 (multiple of 2,3,6)
```

Comment: Great add, +1 to you, thanks Craig.

Comment: You could also possibly do something with Merseine primes, if you're just looking to pad the total primes found, but you'd have to store them in a separate list because they explode in size very quickly and your sieve needs to be ordered.

Comment: Thats the beauty of the challenge we had last night, the ordering didn't matter it was just most primes in the fastest time =) It was really a fun challenge, honestly the most fun I've had in the last few years of being a burnt out programmer.

Comment: this is incorrect.  Let N = 6.  (6*6) + 3 = 39

Comment: Sorry, I was actually wrong about Merseine primes, mixing it with another term.

I was actually thinking about the pattern they showed in xkcd maybe a year or two back.  Multiply all primes together and add (or subtract) 1.  That number must be either prime or a composed of a prime not in the sieve.   Unfortunately, that defeats the purpose of the sieve.  

If you wanted to do it a slightly different and more threaded way, I suppose you could do a modified sieve of eratosthenes.

Each thread then would wind its way down the list, ticking off any offenders.

Comment: @Haile and this is why i am dumb

Comment: @Craig accepted as the best answer, cheers man!